# slick.js performance on 300+ elements

Tags: performance, slick.js

This is my template for my slide item (made up data):

```
<div>

 <div class="previewImage">
  <img src="myimage.png" alt="myImage" />
 </div>

 <div class="summary">
  <span class="desc">desc</span>
  <span class="count">12345</span>
 </div>

</div>
```

This template gets repeated 325 times and initialised into a slick.js component:

```
$("#slider").slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      infinite: false,
      touchMove: false
});
```

This hangs up Chrome / FF / IE for about 2 seconds and sometimes might even give a "This page is freezing your browser -> Kill or Wait" (paraphrased) notification.

I have tried lazyLoading but it did not make that much of a difference (if any... definitely not conceivable difference). I went through slick.js [website / documentation](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and can't see anything else that might help.

Is there anything I can do here or am I simply using the component beyond its specs? 
Any ideas welcome.

Comment: have you tried dynamically deleting hidden slides as well?

Comment: I don't believe `slick.js` is optimized to this extent. There's a lot of DOM manipulation below the skirt. You should report an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues).

Comment: @Brian I'm not sure I follow, how would I scroll to them if I delete them?

Comment: (sorry it only let me tag one person per message) ... 
@Mike Thanks, I have created an issue [here](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/3346).

Answer (score 0):

Change the src to data-lazy . With src, lazyload doesn't work with Slick.